# Getting all MSMQ or IBM WebSphere MQ queue names by WMI

Tags: wmi, ibm-mq, msmq

I'd like to get (MSMQ or IBM WebSphere MQ) queue names and descriptions by wmi. I can see some list from Windows by WMI

MSMQ --> Win32_PerfRawData_msmq_MSMQQueue

IBM MQ --> Win32_PerfFormattedData_MQSeriesServices_MQSeriesQueues

However I have 2 problems.

1. I can't see all the queue names ( I don't know why ). For example in one of my servers there are 94 queues when i check by MQ Explorer but from WMI I can just see 53 of them. There are nothing special or different with the ones that i can see or can't see as much as I checked.
2. In some servers even though there is MSMQ/IBMMQ running, I don't see  Win32_PerfRawData_msmq_MSMQQueue or Win32_PerfFormattedData_MQSeriesServices_MQSeriesQueues classes on WMI.

And I have admin rights.

It'd be really great if you can point some direction.